# Modelling fracture flow in stress field in COMSOL

Tags: fluid-dynamics, comsol, solid-mechanics

I am new to COMSOL and I want to model fluid flow in stress field. As starting point I want a simple 2D box having a fracture from right to left while pressure gradient vertically. I want to know the threshold value of that pressure from top which allows flow of fluid in fracture. Can anyone please suggest me which modules of COMSOL should I be using. I see simple fluid flow in fracture examples but not where impact of pressure controls the flow!

Comment: You should probably ask this in COMSOL Q&A. Also, you might want to improve your question since it is not clear what you want.

Comment: @nicoguaro    I have already asked question there but no response so far. I actually want that the aperture size of fracture(conducting fluid flow) in a body is to be controlled by stress fields present in that body.

Comment: You are probably interested in fluid-structure interaction, but as I mentioned before, this is not the place for asking this particular question.